# Data for mysql table for European states

Tags: mysql

I need to create a mysql database consisting of two tables 'country_master' and 'state_master' which contains all the countries of europe and its corresponding states.

country master table contains country codes and country names, 
state master table contains state code, state name and respective country codes.

Is there a mysql query for creating states for the countries of europe.
I have the country table.

This is my country master query for populating all countries of europe.

```
  INSERT INTO `country_master` (`country_codes`, `country_names`) VALUES
  ('AL', 'Albania'),
  ('AD', 'Andorra'),
  ('AT', 'Austria'),
  ('BE', 'Belgium'),
  ('BA', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina'),
  ('BG', 'Bulgaria'),
  ...
```

Now I need to create a table state_master with all the states of each country.
eg:

```
    INSERT INTO `country_master` (`state_codes`, `state_names`,`country codes`) VALUES
    ('1', 'state1','AL'),
    ('2', 'state2','AL'),
    ('3', 'state3','AD') etc...
```

Does anyone has query or.sql file containing the states of europe.

Comment: Cool Idea.... Let's see what have you coded so far ?

Comment: "Is there a mysql query for this?" A query to do what? You've just described your data, not what you want to do with it.

Comment: i have created country table but not able to find a way to create state table based on the countries.

Comment: @Developer : hey , what is your exact prob , are u unable to create a related table then you should use foreign key concept or do u want to simply run a query and create a table with all the entries ????

Comment: So, you are actually looking for data?

Comment: @Jocelyn : yes thats what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each country in Europe is different and got that way through thousands of years.

There is no common designate for 'state'.

Some countries use Counties, others Provinces, others Region and other things, it really varies from country to country.  As they all have something between country and local district you can use a generic 'area' or 'dstrict' and have it mean whatever a given country is using.

Comment: actually i needed te data. I just needed to know if there are any queries available for creating states of european countries. There are queries or .sql files available for countries.

Comment: It's true that countries have different names, but you can find lists of them on iso.org. For example for [germany](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:DE) or [norway](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:NO). They're called different things, but they're all listed as sub-divisions.  Might be a bit of a task to collect them all into a table, but if you just need it for a couple of countries it shouldn't be too hard. I suppose, if you need it for a project, you could also give the ISO organization some money for exactly what you need...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
CREATE TABLE Country_Master
(
    CountryCode INT,
    CountryName VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (CountryCode),
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE(CountryName)
);

CREATE TABLE State_Master
(
    StateCode INT,
    StateName VARCHAR(50),
    CountryCode INT,
    CONSTRAINT tb2_pk PRIMARY KEY (StateCode),
    CONSTRAINT tb2_uq UNIQUE (StateName),
    CONSTRAINT tb2_fk FOREIGN KEY (CountryCode)
        REFERENCES Country_Master(CountryCode)
);
```

Comment: Actually this is the query for creating tables. I already have done this. I need to populate the table. Sorry if i didnt mentioned that before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found a database with all the states, but with the countries a database exists, only select countries from Europe from the database
https://github.com/Svish/iso-3166-country-codes/blob/master/countries.sql